# Download an xml file from S3 directly to client (without first downloading file into memory)

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I'm drawing a blank on how to do this.

I want to start a download from S3 in a Django view, and stream the download directly to the client.

i.e., avoid downloading the whole thing into memory and then transferring to the client.

I figured out so far that StreamingHTTPResponse would be involved somehow but I'm having trouble putting the pieces together.

I'm using Boto3, Python3, and Django 1.11.

Comment: Have you considered generating a pre-signed URL, and redirecting the client to that?

Comment: does boto have a call that returns a genarator for the file you are downloading? if so you can just create a `StreamingHttpResponse`, otherwise i don't see many other possibility to stream without downloading it first.

Comment: Good point about the pre-signed URL.  That might be simpler and save me some bandwidth.

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url

Comment: @Greg did you manage to work it out? i am having the same problem as you